# javascript validation on comparison of two variables

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="beans.Questionadd" %>

<%
int countanswer=0;
String counter = request.getParameter("counter");
String counter2 = request.getParameter("counter2");
System.out.println("counter  =  "+counter+", counter2 = "+counter2);

int count = 0, count2 = 0;

if(counter!=null)
{
    count =  Integer.parseInt(counter);
    count ++;
}
else
{
    count = 0;
}
System.out.println("count  =  "+count);
Questionadd[] questionadddarray = (Questionadd[])session.getAttribute("questionadddarray");
Questionadd questionadd = questionadddarray[count];

//System.out.println("questionadd.getQuestion()  =  "+questionadd.getQuestion());
String question = questionadd.getQuestion();
String qtype = questionadd.getQuestiontype();
String option1 = questionadd.getOption1();
String option2 = questionadd.getOption2();
String option3 = questionadd.getOption3();
String option4 = questionadd.getOption4();
String answer = questionadd.getAnswer();

%>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

//function clickform on comparing answer with selected option and incementing 
//count2 value

```
function clickform()
{   
    var form = document.getElementById("form-id");

    alert("INSIDE CLICK");


var x = document.myform.option.value;

<%
answer=answer.trim();

%>

var answer = "<%=answer%>";
if(x==answer)
{  
    <% 
        if(counter2 != null)
        {
        count2 = Integer.parseInt(counter2);
        count2 ++;
        }
        else
        {
            count2 = 1;
        }

    %>
}
else
    {
    <% 
        if(counter2 != null)
        {
            count2 = Integer.parseInt(counter2);
        }
        else
        {
            count2 = 0;
        }
    %>
    }

document.getElementById("counter2").value=count2;  

<% System.out.println("count2 "+count2);%>

}
</script>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="question1.jsp" method="post">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td><%=question %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label><input type="radio" name="option" value="<%=option1 %>" required><%=option1%></input></label></td>
<td><label><input type="radio" name="option" value="<%=option2%>"><%=option2%></input></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label><input type="radio" name="option" value="<%=option3%>"><%=option3%></input></label></td>
<td><label><input type="radio" name="option" value="<%=option4%>"><%=option4%></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div style="text-align:center"><button id="form-id" onclick="return clickform();" />NEXT</button></div></td>
<tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="counter" value="<%=count%>">
<input type="hidden" name="counter2" value="<%=count2%>">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

i have been trying javascript validation.actually i have been fetching values from database through bean class and i have shown question with its four option in html table format. when i have been selecting correct option from among four options my count2 variable[count2 variable has to increment its value on getting correct response] is not incrementing .can anyone tell me what is the problem with my *CLICKFORM* function that it is not incrementing count2 value when it gets correct response from the options

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stackoverflow! I recommend you take the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
to know your way arround here (and earn your first badge also ;) ). Also to improve the chances of getting useful answers
please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and also how to create [Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand the difference between server-side and client-side. All code you have inside <%%> it's always executed no matter what, it is server-side code. The value of count2 will always be whatever is in the second if condition, JavasScript has no saying here. That is why you never get the desired value.

Second, you can't use server-side code with client-side as far as JavaScript goes count2 does not exist and is always null